# how to compare two columns in two sheets which contain string values and print the update in another sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

How to compare two columns in two worksheets and print the changes alone in a third sheet ?
The columns two be compared is T in both the sheets, output has to recorded in "Updates" sheet's B column.
Please help me i'm new to vba

Comment: It would depend on the project setup.  If the rows have the same same data but may be out of order is quite different that if the rows are in the same order and only certain cell values in the rows don't match.

Comment: Both the sheets have same columns in the same order, but the row number is different. I have to compare the T column in each sheet based on a key attribute in A column. It's a string type data in T column. Also i have to subtract the two strings and paste only the difference in the third sheet.

Comment: The easiest VBA solution would be to use a Dictionary: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 39 - Dictionaries](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=dND4coLI_B8&index=43&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).  Although you will take a performance hit, this can be easily accomplished using the VLookUp worksheet formula.

Comment: Thank you. I'm just getting started with vba, your help really matters to me

Answer (score 0):

If the "compared output" means V1 - V2, then here is the code.

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("T" & i).Value) Then
            Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("T" & i).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("T" & i).Value - Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("T" & i).Value
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What if the data has some blank cells in the middle? A better approach is to use `End()` or `UsedRange.Rows.Count` to identify the number of rows to loop through.